# Me.Invoke(Delegate) hangs application

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, threadpool, invoke

I'm new to threading and started off by manually starting a thread with `myThread.Start()`. I had everything working perfectly except when it came to closing the status form, the first thread to end would close the form instead of the last. So I then decided to try using `QueueUserWorkItem` and a loop with `handle.waitOne()`.

Now all of a sudden the application has started hanging when it calls `Me.Invoke(disposal)` - in Public Sub wol_SearchCompleted(). The strange thing is that sometimes I step through the code and it hangs on that line and sometimes it works perfectly.

```
Public Class frmMain

Private wolActiveThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount - 1) As ManualResetEvent 'I have tried setting this to wolActiveThreads(1) but there is no difference
Private adActiveThreads(Environment.ProcessorCount - 1) As ManualResetEvent

Private Sub GetMacAddresses(ByVal compCollection As ComputerCollection)
    If compCollection.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    'Work out how many threads to use and how many computers each thread will discover
    Dim numThreads As Integer = wolActiveThreads.Count - 1
    Dim remainder As Double = compCollection.Count Mod numThreads
    Dim numPerThread As Double = (compCollection.Count - remainder) / numThreads

    'Start the threads
    For i As Integer = 0 To numThreads - 1
        Dim startIndex As Integer = (i * numPerThread)
        Dim endIndex As Integer = startIndex + (numPerThread - 1)

        IIf(i = numThreads - 1, endIndex = endIndex + remainder, endIndex = endIndex) 'If this is the last thread add the remainder of computers which didn't devide equally

        Dim threadParams As Object
        threadParams = New Object() {compCollection, startIndex, endIndex} 'Create an object to pass the parameters

        Dim n As Integer = i
        wolInstances(n) = New WOL(wolActiveThreads(n))
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf wolInstances(n).StartMACSearch), threadParams)

    Next

    'If the status dialog isn't displayed, display it
    If statusDialog Is Nothing Then
        statusDialog = New frmStatus
        statusDialog.ShowDialog()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub StatusDialogDisposal()

    'Wait for all of the ADSearcher class threads to finish
    For Each handle As WaitHandle In adActiveThreads
        handle.WaitOne()
    Next
    'Wait for all of the WOL class threads to finish
    For Each handle As WaitHandle In wolActiveThreads
        handle.WaitOne()
    Next

    If statusDialog IsNot Nothing Then 'If another thread hasn't already disposed of the dialog
        statusDialog.Close() 'Close the dialog
        statusDialog.Dispose() 'Dispose of the dialog
        statusDialog = Nothing 'Dereference the diposed dialog to prevent errors
    End If

End Sub

'[WOL Events]
Private Delegate Sub disposeStatus()
Public Sub wol_SearchCompleted()
    Dim disposal As New disposeStatus(AddressOf StatusDialogDisposal)
    Me.Invoke(disposal)
End Sub
```

Class:

```
Public Class WOL

Public Sub New(ByVal doneEvent As ManualResetEvent)

    'Add event handlers
    AddHandler Me.MACAddressFound, AddressOf frmMain.wol_MACAddressFound
    AddHandler Me.SearchCompleted, AddressOf frmMain.wol_SearchCompleted

    _doneEvent = doneEvent

End Sub

Public Sub StartMACSearch(ByVal parameters As Object)
    _doneEvent.Reset() 'Make sure the thread pool knows the thread is still working

    Dim computerList As ComputerCollection = parameters(0)
    Dim startIndex As Integer = parameters(1)
    Dim endIndex As Integer = parameters(2)

    macsFound = 0

    For i As Integer = startIndex To endIndex
        GetMACAddress(computerList(i).FQDN)
    Next

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Thread " + startIndex.ToString + " to " + endIndex.ToString + " is ending")

    RaiseEvent SearchCompleted()
    _doneEvent.Set() 'Signal that the thread is finished

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So do I need to show statusDialog on its own thread to solve the problem?

Comment: I read an answer to somebody elses question which says its not recommended to create a form in a new thread. All UI's should be run on the main thread (although it doesn't explain why).So apart from that the only other ways I can think of are to use an if statement to manually check the state of the threads and exit sub unless it is the last thread calling

Comment: Hit enter by mistake and posted that too soon. Here's what it should say:

I read an answer to somebody elses question which says its not recommended to create a form in a new thread. All UI's should be run on the main thread (although it doesn't explain why).

So apart from that the only other ways I can think of are to use an if statement to manually check the state of the threads and exit sub unless it is the last thread calling, then invoke the form disposal (instead of handle.WaitOne()). But I don't know if this is good practice? (or if it's possible)

Comment: Or to move the loop which waits for the threads into the WOL class and wait for the threads to finish before raising the SearchCompleted event. But that would mean accessing the wolActiveThreads array cross thread which I assume I could do by invoking a function which would pass the array across the threads. But again I don't know if this will work or if it is good practice?

I don't have time to play around and try these options until tomorrow evening, but if anybody could suggest the best option I would be grateful.

Comment: Are you using .net 3.5 or higher? If so the task API is a better way  of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I left it on the default for VS2012 so .Net 4.5. Would you be able to give me an example or link please as I'm not sure what you're referring to. Many thanks.

Comment: When you say the app "hangs" what do you mean?  Do you mean that the UI is not responsive?  Is there an exception?  Is the StatusDialog visible at the time?

Comment: statusDialog is visible at the time and the marquee progress bar stops. The UI is then completely unresponsive. I have now removed the handle.WaitOne() loops and replaced them with an int which counts how many times the sub is called. Then use if int >= number of threads. Although this works fine for my needs I assume there is a better method to handle this situation?